# How to detect newly introduced code smell/leak using sonarlint extension for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

We are using sonarlint extension for visual studio to analyze our code by connecting to our project’s rule profile. However, we need to detect code smell introduced by newly added code and not analysis report for each worked file. For example one file might have 50 legacy issues but if my newly added code fixes 10 issues but in turn introduces 5 new issues then I need to see those 5 issues locally in visual studio.

This is the same way teamcity is giving us scan report after build. Please suggest how can I detect new leak using sonarlint and visual studio

Comment: _"[this] is not part of the short-term roadmap"_ - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-700

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the developers of the tool have said it is not on their roadmap

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which analyzers you are wanting to see live in Visual Studio, but you could consider adding the SonarAnalyzer as a nuget package to your assemblies to get Roslyn based feedback for the analyzers that it supports. Here's the nuget link to this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/.